# how to skip a single number from integer array

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my code i can able to get first five integer and i can skip first three integer
i need to skip a single number from this array .
  how may i achieve with this code?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        var result1 = ints.Take(5);
        var result2 = ints.Skip(3);
        Array.ForEach(result1.ToArray(), n => Console.WriteLine(n));
        Console.ReadLine();
        Array.ForEach(result2.ToArray(), n => Console.WriteLine(n));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Clarification: i need to skip ints[4], so i want only 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: A single number with a specific value, or a single number in a specific position?

Comment: So you want a new array WITHOUT a number from the first array?

Comment: @Steve array is given above i need to skip one number from that array\

Comment: @Mazz: you're talking in riddles. Do you want to skip a specific number, if so, do you want to skip only the first of this number (in case of multiple) or all. If not, what means _"skip one number"_? What is the desired result from your array?

Comment: @Mazz - you're not being clear enough at all. Give examples of data you'd feed in, data/elements you'd omit (based on an explicit criteria) and data (including the type) you'd end up with.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sry.i think my array having 10 integer i need to skip any one of the integer from any position

Comment: @Mazz: that sounds still arbitrary. _What_ numbers do you want to skip? How do you determine that number(s)? Is it at a random index or has it a specific value?

Comment: i need to skip ints[4] @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Mazz: i have edited your question, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you want to skip a specific index you can use the overload of [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = ints.Where((i, index) => index != 4);
```

If you instead  want to skip all 3 in the array:

```
var result = ints.Where(i => i != 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response =D

Comment: @Mazz: note that i've edited my answer to show also how to skip a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter an array using the [`IEnumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var numberToOmit = 5;
var filteredList = ints.Where(number => number != numberToOmit).toList();
filteredList.forEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Comment: I don't know... we all got down voted with no expiation what we did wrong...

Comment: Some people seem to think that all answers to poor questions should be downvoted. I don't agree. I think there can be good answers to bad questions. And questions can be salvaged.

Comment: I don't want to make conclusions. At least they got voted all back up to 0

Comment: I don't agree that providing answers based on assumptions is the best approach at all of 'salvaging' a bad question. SO is about being explicit about requirements and addressing specific technical problems, the OP should be asked to clarfiy before answers are given. It, otherwise, just adds noise. Potentially irrelevant noise.

Comment: @DeeMac Granted, the question may be a bit fuzzy. But it appeared sufficiently clear for me to provide an answer. Since stackoverflow attracts an international user base I wouldn't expect flawless and unambiguous writing before attempting to answer.

Comment: @DennisTraub Thanks for your response =D

Comment: This post hit Low Quality Queue. I disagree with outright deletion of the answer.

Comment: I think you hit "low quality review queue" because there is only code in there. Try adding a little explanation of what you did and why it works. Should bump you out of the queue.

Comment: @DennisTraub - neither would I, which is why the comment functionality serves it's purpose as a way of requesting clarification. You offered a solution based on the OP wanting to omit an element based on it's value, while others were still asking whether it's value-based or index-based omission. It could mislead somebody who was led here with the same problem as OPs and is potentially irrelevant, hence your 2 down-votes.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers, this will allow you to skip a particular position in the array.

```
 List<int> output = new List<int>();
 int skipIteration = 3;
 for (int x = 0; x < ints.Length; x++)
 {
      if (x != skipIteration)
      {
          output.Add(ints[x]);
      }
 }

ints = output.ToArray();
```

this is the "quick" way without accounting for performance/reducing allocation

Comment: Thanks for your response =D @serguei

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it helped!